# Update the next row of the target row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table that tracks if a payment is missed like this:

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
| id | loan_id | amount_due |   due_at   | paid_at | missed |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|  1 |    1    |        100 | 2013-08-17 | NULL    | NULL   |
|  5 |    1    |        100 | 2013-09-17 | NULL    | NULL   |
|  7 |    1    |        100 | 2013-10-17 | NULL    | NULL   |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
```

And, for example, I ran a query that checks if a payment is missed like this:

```
UPDATE loan_payments
SET missed = 1
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), due_at) >= 10
AND paid_at IS NULL
```

Then suppose that the row with id = 1 gets affected. I want the amount_due of row with id = 1 be added to the amount_due of the next row so the table would look like this:

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
| id | loan_id | amount_due |   due_at   | paid_at | missed |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |        100 | 2013-08-17 | NULL    |      1 |
|  5 |       1 |        200 | 2013-09-17 | NULL    | NULL   |
|  7 |       1 |        100 | 2013-10-17 | NULL    | NULL   |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
```

Any advice on how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to do this purely through SQL, or through PHP/Java/.NET/etc?

Comment: @musical_coder I'm using PHP but if it can be done using pure SQL, that would be great. This is for a cron job and I prefer not to use a PHP loop to achieve this, if it's possible.

Comment: @AsshO.Le because I want to achieve this as efficient as possible. That's why I don't want to use PHP loops if this can be achieved using pure SQL.

Comment: There is something wrong with your db. Do you have `CUSTOMER_ID`?  or `TRANSACTION_HDR`? This will eliminate your worry on how to change the next bill. This design of yours is not advisable if you are making a small billing system. If I'm mistaken, please provide your table schema.

Comment: @ChristianMark actually there is a loan_id because it's a payment table for a loan. But I didn't think it's relevant in this question. However, if you feel it's important, please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, it is important. You see, you have the `LOAN_ID`. Now you don't need to update the next row just to show the total amount to be paid on the next billing. If you have the interest rate to be applied on that 'missed' payment, you only have to create a good query for that. I think you don't want to create such complex query.

Comment: @ChristianMark Can you make an example? I'm trying to update the next row, so the amount_due is added to it, not the row that is the target of the "missed payment checker".

Comment: Are you trying to get that `SUM` of due payments?

Comment: @ChristianMark No. I'm trying to add the amount_due of the missed payment to the amount_due of the next payment. So all in all, I need to update two rows: one, to set the "missed" flag to "1", two: to set the amount_due of the next payment = amount_due of "missed" payment + amount_due of next payment.

Comment: @SandyandiN.delaCruz does this need to happen in all records the as exceeded the first due date?

Comment: @AsshO.Le Yes. There could be hundreds of loans and each has it own payments table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e198e/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE loan_payments
    (`id` int, `loan_id` int, `amount_due` int, 
     `due_at` varchar(10), `paid_at` varchar(4), `missed` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO loan_payments
    (`id`, `loan_id`, `amount_due`, `due_at`, `paid_at`, `missed`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 100, '2013-09-17', NULL, NULL),
    (3, 2, 100, '2013-09-17', NULL, NULL),
    (5, 1, 100, '2013-10-17', NULL, NULL),
    (7, 1, 100, '2013-11-17', NULL, NULL)
;

UPDATE loan_payments AS l
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT loan_id, MIN(ID) AS ID
            FROM loan_payments
            WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), due_at) < 0
            GROUP BY loan_id) AS l2 ON l.loan_id = l2.loan_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN loan_payments AS l3 ON l2.id = l3.id
SET l.missed = 1, l3.amount_due = l3.amount_due + l.amount_due
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), l.due_at) >= 10
AND l.paid_at IS NULL
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM loan_payments
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e198e/1/0)**:

```
| ID | LOAN_ID | AMOUNT_DUE |     DUE_AT | PAID_AT | MISSED |
|----|---------|------------|------------|---------|--------|
|  1 |       1 |        100 | 2013-09-17 |  (null) |      1 |
|  3 |       2 |        100 | 2013-09-17 |  (null) |      1 |
|  5 |       1 |        200 | 2013-10-17 |  (null) | (null) |
|  7 |       1 |        100 | 2013-11-17 |  (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, there's a problem with this query. It won't update a row if it has no succeeding row of the same loan_id. For example: there's only one row that has loan_id = 2. It won't update it to missed = 1.

Comment: @SandyandiN.delaCruz I updated the query to consider this situation

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have time at the moment to write out full-blown SQL, but here's the psuedocode I think you need to implement:

```
select all DISTINCT loan_id from table loan_payments

for each loan_id:
    set missed = 1 for all outstanding payments for loan_id (as determined by date)
    select the sum of all outstanding payments for loan_id
    add this sum to the amount_due for the loan's next due date after today
```

Refer to this for how to loop using pure MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html

Comment: op said he want it in the most efficient way?

Comment: @AsshO.Le: your guess is as good as mine :) I added the DISTINCT keyword to my psuedocode so no duplicate `load_id` are selected from `loan_payments`. At the moment, I can't think of a way to do this without a loop, but if you do, please post it.

Comment: sorry im not familiar in mysql :) but in mssql i rather slect all the top 2 nulls :) and process them :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own problem by adding a `missed_at` field. I put the current timestamp (`$now`) in a variable before I update the first row to `missed` = 1 and `missed_at` = `$now` then I ran this query to update the next row's `amount_due`:

```
UPDATE loan_payments lp1 JOIN loan_payments lp2 ON lp1.due_at > lp2.due_at
SET lp1.amount_due = lp2.amount_due + lp1.amount_due
WHERE lp2.missed_at = $now AND DATEDIFF(lp1.due_at, lp2.due_at) <= DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(lp1.due_at))
```

I wish I could use just use `LIMIT 1` to that query but it turns out that it's not possible for an `UPDATE` query with a `JOIN`.

So all in all, I used two queries to achieve what I want. It did the trick.

Please advise if you have better solutions.

Thanks!